# Reading a Bluetooth LE array from UUID?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read data from an array which was sent to me by a Bluetooth LE device.

The data stream should be 18 bytes and, when viewed as an array, I need bytes 5, 6, and 7.

I have the correct UUID for the `service` and `characteristic`. However, I cannot figure out how to get the array from `characteristic`.

Right now I am simply trying to get data that I recognize. However, the log statement below yields random characters that I cannot understand or match to data.

The only really important line in this function is the log with `characteristic.getValue()` but I figured I would include the entire thing for a bit of context.

```
 @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "characteristic read: "+characteristic.getValue());
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            gatt.readRemoteRssi();
            runOnUiThread(update_UI);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            gatt.discoverServices();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding brackets with my desired byte at the end of the array gave me the data I wanted.

`Log.d(TAG, "characteristic read: "+characteristic.getValue()[4]);` will give me the fourth byte.